# About closure of sets in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

We know that let $\{A_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of sets in a topological space with euclidean topology

\begin{equation}
\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty}A_{i}}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty}\bar{A_{i}}\cup \bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}\overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^{+\infty}A_{i+j}}.
\end{equation}

Do exists conditions such that

\begin{equation}
\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty}A_{i}}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty}\bar{A_{i}}.
\end{equation}
Where $\bar{A_{i}}$ represents the closure of $A_{i}$

Thanks!

Comment: e.g. if $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq\ldots$ or if $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i =  \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i $ for some $N$

Comment: Any particular condition on your $A_i$ sets?  Are these elements of the topology?  Youve tagged this with topology and your question has to do with closure, as opposed to tagging with general set theory, so Im not entirely sure on the nature of your question.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Without topology, no $\overline{\quad\strut}$ (or one with different meaning)

Comment: Overline is a set complement notation, by all instances of its use Ive ever seen.

Comment: The intent of this question is not obvious, else Id assume it would be answered by now. The question asks for closure. Its tagged with topology, not set theory. But text content explicitly says "in general", and shows the union and intersection of sets and their complements, and nothing particular to topology. I dont know if $A$ is an open set. I dont even know if $A$ represents a set!  No elaboration whatsoever.  And Im not one to make assumptions in math. Should I not be confused by this question? It is far too vaguely written.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I've mostly seen the overline to represent set closure in topological settings and the superscript $c$ to represent complement. I think it's fairly obvious that the notation in the question is referring to set closure. If anything, the reason the question hasn't been answered is because it's too general, i.e. there are plenty of cases when the statement might hold, but without knowing which ones the asker cares about I would hold off on putting together an elaborate answer. It would help to know what problem they're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I have seen superscript $c$ as well, but not very common. I have seen $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ to represent closure, as well as $\overset{\circ}{A}$.  But Ive never seen the overline used in that way.  I appreciate you pointing out the utter lack of consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the question update @Jack

Comment: So in the event that overline represents closure, Id like to point out that your first block-level mathematical statement isnt generally true.  The left hand side is closed, by definition.  But on the right hand side, you cannot guarantee that infinite union of closed sets is closed.  Im not sure if its relevant... I need to think about it more but it is something I readily noticed.  If that first union on the right hand side is completely contained in the intersection, it wont matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One condition is quite natural: We have that $A_n$ is a so-called closure preserving family (which implies your identity), when $\{A_n: n=1,2,3\}$ is locally finite. This means that  for every $x \in X$, there exists an open neighbourhoods $O_x$ of $x$ such that $\{n : O_x \cap A_n \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite.